# Effect size for Kruskal-Wallis, Epsilon and Eta flipped?

Tags: statistics

Tomczak and Tomczak (2014) is often used as a source to select an appropriate effect size. It shows on page 24 a formula for eta-squared and epsilon-sequared for use with a Kruskal-Wallis test.

However, if I simply use the regular formula for the epsilon-squared and eta-squared on the data ranked, I get the exact same results, but eta-squared (original formula) is then the same as the epsilon-squared from Tomczak and Tomczak, and the other way around.

Did they perhaps mistakenly flip these two by accident? Or am I overlooking something?

The formula's from Tomczak and Tomczak:

$$\epsilon_{TT}^2=H\times\frac{n+1}{n^2-1}$$
$$\eta_{TT}^2=\frac{H-k+1}{n-k}$$

The regular formula's (for example epsilon sq from Albers and Lakens (2018, p. 188), and eta-sq from Pearson (1911, p. 254)):
$$\epsilon^2 = \frac{SS_b - df_b\times MS_w}{SS_t}$$
$$\eta^2 = \frac{SS_b}{SS_t}$$

References:

- Albers, C., & Lakens, D. (2018). When power analyses based on pilot data are biased: Inaccurate effect size estimators and follow-up bias. *Journal of Experimental Social Psychology, 74*, 187–195. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jesp.2017.09.004
- Pearson, K. (1911). On a correction to be made to the correlation ratio η. *Biometrika, 8*(1/2), 254. doi:10.2307/2331454
- Tomczak, M., & Tomczak, E. (2014). The need to report effect size estimates revisited. An overview of some recommended measures of effect size. *Trends in Sport Sciences, 1*(21), 19–25.